# How to use group concat with group by?

Tags: mysql

Here my table is having filed as following:

```
employee_id,
expense_id,
expense_type,
expense_cost,
expense_date and etc,
```

And i want to display as month wise expenses as row wise for particular employee.
in my table data has stored like

```
2wheeler        01/03/2014  99  Santhosh    4493.00     March       500.00
Auto            03/02/2014  99  Santhosh    0.00        February    80.00
Food            01/02/2014  99  Santhosh    0.00        February    200.00
Phone Expense   01/03/2014  99  Santhosh    0.00        March       500.00
```

In this table i want to get out as 
single user row with concat of expense type and sum of cost for every month that mean : march have single row with concat of expense type & sum of cost.

Comment: can you display the desired output

Comment: 01/03/2014 99 san 4493.00 mar 500 2wheeler:4493|pho exp:0.00                    01/02/2014 99 san 0.00 mar 0.00 auto:4493|food:0.00                    this is the sample output format. help me how to get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing a sub query that sums up all the occurances of an expenses per employee per month per expense. Then use that as a source to get the list of employees, months and the GROUP_CONCATed list of expense types and the total cost of them.

Like this:-

```
SELECT employee_id, expense_month, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', expense_type, monthly_exployee_expense))
FROM
(
    SELECT employee_id, MONTH(expense_date) AS expense_month, expense_type, SUM(expense_cost) AS monthly_exployee_expense
    FROM some_table
    GROUP BY employee_id, expense_month, expense_type
) Sub1
GROUP BY employee_id, expense_month
```

EDIT

Reading you comment it seems that you need an expense listed even when an employee has not incurred that expense that month.

To do that I think you will need to cross join the employees (I have assumed a table name of tbl_employee) with the table of expenses types, and also all the possible months (assuming you want a row for a month for an employee when that employee has had no expenses that month). I have got the possible months by just selecting the distinct year / month from the table listing all the expenses (but there are other ways to get this - depends if there are any months where no employees had any expenses and if you want to put these out anyway).

Once those are cross joined to get every combination of employee, month and expense you can left join the actual expenses in the sub query, and then do the GROUP_CONCAT much as before.

Not tested, but something like this:-

```
SELECT employee_id, expense_month, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', exp_type_text, monthly_exployee_expense))
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl_employee.employee_id, expense_months.expense_month, tbl_expense_type.exp_type_id, tbl_expense_type.exp_type_text, SUM(expense_cost) AS monthly_exployee_expense
    FROM tbl_employee
    CROSS JOIN tbl_expense_type
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(expense_date, '%Y%m') AS expense_month
        FROM some_table
    ) expense_months
    LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table
    ON tbl_employee.employee_id = some_table.employee_id
    AND tbl_expense_type.exp_type_id = some_table.expense_type
    AND expense_months.expense_month = DATE_FORMAT(some_table.expense_date, '%Y%m')
    GROUP BY tbl_employee.employee_id, expense_months.expense_month, tbl_expense_type.exp_type_id, tbl_expense_type.exp_type_text
) Sub1
GROUP BY employee_id, expense_month
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. its works fine. in that mentioned expense type text is shows as id only, i have to pick that from master table. in that master table unused id will have to concat with cost of 0. means : Phone Expense=500,2 wheeler=4493                                      above is got out put. i want like as Phone Expense=500,2 wheeler=4493, food=0,stay=0,.. like wise.. how to achieve that?

Comment: For that you will need to join to the table that lists the possible expense types and the text for them. Can you post the table declare for that?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_expense_type` (
  `exp_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `exp_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exp_type_text` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_delete` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_delete_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_delete_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`exp_type_id`)                                        ); this s the table format.. guide me the join query for this table